# Installing KDE alongside GNOME

Tags: kde

I'm using Ubuntu with the standard GNOME environment. I'd like to use the KDE desktop, but I don't want to install the apps, I'd rather use the same applications I already have installed for GNOME. Which package installs only the desktop environment without any of the apps that are part of kubuntu-desktop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `plasma-desktop` would best fit your needs

> Provides the environment for running and managing applications and integrating
>   interaction of applications. It is designed as generic environment for all
>   kinds of desktop applications, not only applications built on the KDE Platform.
>   It integrates best with applications following the standards used by the KDE
>   Platform.

Comment: This worked, thanks. There's only one major problem, all the GTK apps aren't themed like KDE app. They have that ugly theme that usually comes when there is no theme at all or something is broken with the configuration. Do I have to install some other package to fix that?

Comment: @satuon which version of KDE did you install ?

Comment: The theme is Raleigh, and you need a theme callled oxygen gtk for kde to theme gtk apps under kde-

Comment: @m-night-shyamalan I typed 'sudo apt-get install plasma-desktop' so it would be whatever comes from the standard repositories (I'm on maverick).

Answer (score 1):

I've used this before and it works pretty good [UKubuntizald Tutorial: Ubuntu + KDE Plasma Workspace](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1291048)