# Can I install the GUI from ZorinOS?

Tags: 11.10, gui

I'm current using Ubuntu 11.10 and want to "try something old" on my machine (Window-like GUI). So if anyone know how to install [ZorinOS GUI](http://zorin-os.com/) on Ubuntu 11.10 system ([like we can do with KDE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50892/installing-kde-alongside-gnome)), please tell me about it. Many thanks!

Comment: you mean install windows theme in ubuntu 11.10?
It is already answered in another question 
still it is not complete
because 
there in no gtk3 win7 theme available
gnomenu wont support etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Windows-like GUI that ZorinOS uses is LXDE. You can install this from the repos (apt-get install lxde) then theme it, or you could install the lubuntu-desktop package and get the Lubuntu themed version of LXDE

Comment: That's interesting! If you have experience with this, it would be nice if you could elaborate on that.