# Looking for help installing KDE

Tags: kde

I'm trying to install KDE Plasma 5.9 and I'm getting stuck at the first step of adding the ppa. I run the command

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
```

but then the terminal gives me the following

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 11, in <module>

from softwareproperties.SoftwareProperties import SoftwareProperties, shortcut_handler

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 28, in <module>

import apt_pkg

ImportError: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_pkg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: invalid ELF header

Error in sys.excepthook:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook

from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>

from apport.report import Report

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>

import apport.fileutils

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>

from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 24, in <module>

import apt

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>

import apt_pkg

ImportError: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_pkg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: invalid ELF header


Original exception was:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 11, in <module>

from softwareproperties.SoftwareProperties import SoftwareProperties, shortcut_handler

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 28, in <module>

import apt_pkg

ImportError: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_pkg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: invalid ELF header
```

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 Kernel 4.17.13

I tried to uninstall and reinstall python but that didn't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing KDE alongside GNOME](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50892/installing-kde-alongside-gnome)

Comment: **1:** Although some people have success in running both environments on the same system, be prepared for the unexpected. Just running individual GNOME apps on KDE works fine and vice versa but have both DEs together can cause conflicts. **2:** Can you run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt full-upgrade` without any unusual messages appearing in the terminal output? **3:** I'm not sure that the ppa in question is designed for usage by users who aren't already running **K**ubuntu.